# error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Camera.ScreenPointToRay(UnityEngine.Vector3)'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm really not sure whats wrong...

im following along to a YouTube Video because this code is much too advanced for me. I dont know if its a problem with unity 5 or whatever but it just keeps giving me this error:  error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Camera.ScreenPointToRay(UnityEngine.Vector3)'

I know its probably a bad idea to copy from YouTube without knowing what it means but im just trying to get a script for touchscreen stuff.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TouchInput : MonoBehaviour {

public LayerMask touchInputMask;

private List<GameObject> touchList = new List<GameObject>();
private GameObject[] touchesOld;

private RaycastHit hit;

void Update () {

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {

        touchesOld = new GameObject[touchList.Count];
        touchList.CopyTo(touchesOld);
        touchList.Clear();

        Ray ray = Camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit,touchInputMask)){

            GameObject recipient = hit.transform.gameObject;
            touchList.Add(recipient);

            if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
                recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchDown",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
            if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){
                recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchUp",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
            if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
                recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchStay",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
        }

        foreach (GameObject g in touchesOld){
            if(!touchList.Contains(g)){
                g.SendMessage("OnTouchExit",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
        }
    }
    #endif

    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {

        touchesOld = new GameObject[touchList.Count];
        touchList.CopyTo(touchesOld);
        touchList.Clear();

        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {

            Ray ray = Camera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);

            if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit,touchInputMask)){

                GameObject recipient = hit.transform.gameObject;
                touchList.Add(recipient);

                if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began){
                    recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchDown",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
                if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended){
                    recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchUp",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
                if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved){
                    recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchStay",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
                if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled){
                    recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchExit",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
            }

        }
        foreach (GameObject g in touchesOld){
            if(!touchList.Contains(g)){
                g.SendMessage("OnTouchExit",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a Unity expert, but the documentation says that ScreenPointToRay is an instance method, not a static method.  This means that you would have to create an instance of Camera before using it.  So, perhaps:

```
camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
```

Note that there are two places in your code snippet where you'd need to make this change.